# "invalid option" when running Yeoman Webapp + Compass

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bower, yeoman, compass

I'm new to Yeoman and I`m trying to setup a yeoman bootstrap sass/compass enviroment.

I've followed this [link](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) for the creation of the Yeoman Webapp.

And this [link](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/compass.md) to the compass recipe.

When I run grunt serve I get the following:
Running tasks: compass:server

```
Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.server exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="app/styles", cssDir=".tmp/styles", imagesDir="app/images", javascriptsDir="app/scripts", fontsDir="app/styles/fonts", generatedImagesDir=".tmp/images/generated", importPath="bower_components", httpImagesPath="../images", httpGeneratedImagesPath="../images/generated", httpFontsPath="fonts", relativeAssets=false, assetCacheBuster=false, debugInfo
Error: invalid option: --import-path=bower_components

Usage: compass compile [path/to/project] [path/to/project/src/file.sass ...] [options]
```

I have searched around all over to fix the issue with no success any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by upgrading Compass...